# AES Library or code for C++

Tags: c++, encryption, aes, twofish

I'm supposed to overload the class below twice. Once I'm supposed to implement it with AES (Rijndael) and once with Twofish. However, I can't seem to find a simple implementation that allows to encrypt only a single block. The implementations I found come with included CBC and Padding. Any hint?

```
#ifndef CRYPTER_H
#define CRYPTER_H

#include <valarray>

class Crypter {
public:
    Crypter();
    virtual ~Crypter();

    //Encrypts a single block of 16 byte.
    virtual std::valarray<unsigned char> encrypt(std::valarray<unsigned char> plaintext,
            std::valarray<unsigned char> passphrase) = 0;

    //Decrypts a single block of 16 byte.
    virtual std::valarray<unsigned char> decrypt(std::valarray<unsigned char> cyphertext,
            std::valarray<unsigned char> passphrase) = 0;     
};
#endif  /* CRYPTER_H */
```

Comment: Have you checked OpenSSL and Crypto++?

Comment: openssl supports CTR mode, and so probably does crypto++

Comment: Try also PolarSSL aka mbedTLS. There is AES implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Openssl is the best crypto library for C/C++ and I think it's definitely worth to give it a look.

You can always break data yourself into blocks and encrypt/decrypt with library functions.

Comment: It is not the best library, but is widely used in Linux, etc.

Comment: @i486: In OSS cryptography, "widely used" is a strength in and of itself. However, OpenSSL doesn't have a Twofish implementation AFAIK...?

Comment: Found it :-) I can copy the source code from aes_x86core.c. However, there's no Twofish implementation.

Comment: @Aptitude: The idea is to *use* a library (and benefit from future releases), not copy its source code...